# python how to dump dynamic create class to file

Tags: python, django, metaclass, inspect

I had been dynamic create a python meta class

I want to dump it to a python file

```
cls = type("ClsName", (object, ), attr)
code = xxxGetSource(cls)
writeToFile(code, "moduleName/ClsName.py")
```

I need this, because when django makemigrations, it need to found the metaclass for model, but my model metaclass was dynamic generate

```
class XXXModel(GenerateCls({ .... }),
               models.Model):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Django does have tools that enable doing this, it is not actually needed.
What you need to have is that upon importing `models.py`, your dynamically created classes must be available on the module namespace.

So, all you have to do is to call upon whatever code does create the classes in code at the `models.py` module level, and ensure they are visible there - it can be as simple as:

```py
from django.db import models

def create_classes():
    Meta = type("Meta", (), {"app_label": "test2"})
    DynamicUser = type("DynamicUser", (models.Model,), {"name": models.TextField(255), "__module__": __file__, "Meta": Meta})
    return DynamicUser


DynamicUser = create_classes()
```

if you don't know at coding time the name and quantity of classes, then you can update the dicionary returned by `globals()` with the classes and their names.
Let's suppose the `create_classes` function would return a list contaning classes - one could do this in `models.py`

```py
def materialize_for_migration():
    classes = create_classes
    globals().update({cls.__name__: cls for cls in classes})

materialize_for_migration()
```